# WSL2 Routing and NAT Rules

Tags: windows-10, networking, hyper-v, nat, wsl2

I recently installed WSL2 on my Windows 10 PC and I'm trying to understand how traffic is handled to and from WSL2. The below article states that WSL2 is running as a managed Hyper-V VM and uses a NAT service for its virtual network, which is fine and I understand.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions

However, I'd like to know how to list, and eventually manipulate, those NAT rules for specific use cases. For example, let's say my PC has two physical NICs (LAN1 and LAN2) available with two different IPs assigned to them. By default, Windows 10 is routing and SNAT-ing all outbound WSL2 traffic via LAN1. How would I configure Windows 10 to instead route and SNAT all outbound WSL2 traffic via LAN2?

So far, I haven't found any type of solution for this. I've used the "Get-NetNat" Powershell cmdlet to list NAT rules, but nothing comes up. The "Get-NetRoute" cmdlet doesn't list any forwarding rules that would explain how Windows 10 chooses where to forward outbound WSL2 traffic. Are there any other commands or utilities that I should be using for these things?

I've also dumped the entire Windows 10 network configuration using the "netsh" utility, but there is no mention of any NAT or forwarding rules. The only relevant part of the dump I could find is the IPv4 configuration for the WSL2 virtual adapter:

```
set interface interface="vEthernet (WSL)" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled nud=enabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled
add address name="vEthernet (WSL)" address=172.27.128.1 mask=255.255.240.0
```

Strangely, the Hyper-V "Get-VM" cmdlet doesn't even recognize WSL2 as a managed VM, it doesn't come up. Why is that? Is there another way to check what VMs are running on the host?

Comment: Would this gist on github provide any clues? https://gist.github.com/the-moog/e7a1b5150ce9017309afbcf91848e622

Comment: This is such a good question, it is too bad nobody has answered it!

Comment: Somehow it uses the same facility as the "Default Switch" in hyper-v, and I suspect it is Host Networking Services and ICS (Internet Connection Sharing) but they are configured in a very obtuse way. For my purposes, knowing it is *not* using NetNat actually is very useful.